# write query in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rgt, @myWidth := rgt - lft + 1
FROM nested_category
WHERE name = 'MP3 PLAYERS';

DELETE FROM nested_category WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight;

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

my codeigniter code:

```
function deletecategory($id)
{   
      $Q = $this->db->query('SELECT  * FROM categorymaster where cat = "'.$id.'"');

        if ($Q->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                        foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row)
                        {
                            $rightextent = $row['rightextent'];
                            $leftextent = $row['leftextent'];
                            $width=$rightextent-$leftextent+1;
                        }
                } else {
                    $rightextent=0;
                }

            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $this->db->delete('categorymaster');

            $width=$rightextent-$leftextent+1;

            $Q2 = $this->db->query('update categorymaster set rightextent=rightextent-"'.$width.'" where rightextent > "'.$rightextent.'"');

            $Q1 = $this->db->query('update categorymaster set leftextent=leftextent-"'.$width.'" where leftextent > "'.$rightextent.'"');
}
```

when I delete the root node at that time also delete their child node and also update their right and left extent

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: This approach works equally well to delete a node and all its children. i want this code in codeigniter

Comment: @madhuri You can't just post your code without any question. Please tell the the visitors that whats your actual question

Comment: @MadhuriPatel Well, then try it in CodeIgniter. If you run into any problems while trying to do that then post a question here regarding that. Please understand that **we here are not a CODE-VENDING MACHINE!!**

Comment: @MadhuriPatel Oh glad to see that you do!! Thumbs Up!!! So please ask a specific question if you have one rather than "i want this code in codeigniter". Well, if you want this code in CodeIgniter, then you're gonna have to write it!!!

Comment: @MadhuriPatel Try to do it yourself. If you come across a situation where you need guidance and/or help with a specific situation, then post a question here and I'm sure the folks here will be glad to help!!

Comment: now i want help..becoz from my code delete root node but not its child nodes..

Comment: if u have solution then please help me.

Comment: i attached my codeigniter code..please see it.